# Connect to a heroku server with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, connection

How would one go about connecting to a heroku node.js server? For example, I have a server named 'https://example.herokuapp.com/' that uses node.js. How would I connect to it from a normal javascript file running socket.io. The code might look something like this:

```
var socket = io();
socket.connect('https://example.herokuapp.com/', { autoConnect: true});
```

I have tried this and I get the output of

```
polling-xhr.js:261 GET http://file/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LjFlRl1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

So would I need an IP for the heroku server? If so how do I get it and is it even possible with heroku. If you're wondering why I don't host the html file on heroku it's because I'm using it for a website and my web host doesn't support node.js hosting. So I decided to host the node.js server on heroku. Thanks for your help in advance.

Server code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
 console.log('connection' + socket.id)

 socket.emit('ping', {
  data: 'ping',
 });
});
```

Comment: "Name not resolved" means the address you are connecting to isn't available via DNS. Are you sure you haven't typo'ed your Heroku hostname? What does the server code look like?

Comment: @elithrar do you mean the code the server runs on? It doesn't output any errors. So I'm assuming that's what you mean

Comment: @elithrar I updated the code if you wanted to see it